# OpenNI/rviz connection to Kinect failed

Tags: kinect, rviz, openni, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, ros hydro, openni and now I'm trying desperately to connect my kinect to rviz.
My aim is to realize a SLAM algorithm on my Eddie robot, therfore i use the guide of Dr. Rainer Hessmer: 2d SLAM with ROS and Kinect. I would give you the link, but i have to less karma..;-)

The first steps are easy, installing the ros and openni doesn't make any problems. But after the install process, neither rviz nor openni is able to locate the kinect: rviz says: No tf data.  Actual error: Fixed Frame [openni_camera] does not exist.,openni says: no device connected (after using roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch to start the framework.).

Ubuntu itself connects with the kinect: lsusb displays the connections, so i think the drivers which come with openni are actually working.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?
Thanks for your help!!!

Robin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121471/openni/rviz-connection-to-kinect-failed/) by [Rolias](https://answers.ros.org/users/11131/rolias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright you should give a little bit more detail about your specific problems but I'm guessing these two links should help:

http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch

http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/QuickStart

---

Originally posted by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) with karma: 429 on 2014-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0